# Choosing between frontend and backend

Tags: server, front-end, server-side

I am new to web development. After reading some posts, such as [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/368443/do-cpu-intensive-data-intensive-tasks-belong-on-the-server) and [this](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-decide-whether-a-set-of-computations-should-be-done-on-front-end-or-back-end), I am still not sure which parts of my application belong to backend. To make things simple, I will use a mock example. The workflow is as follows:

1. The user provides my app with an API key for a third-party service capable of translating a file from a .WAV audio format into a file in the .MP3 format. The third party charges the user per file, so that the API key is sensitive information.
2. My app receives from the user a number of .WAV clips, translates them using the third-party service and the API key provided by the user, concatenates the resulting .MP3 clips and lets the user listen to or download the resulting clip.

I could do everything (i.e. both sending request to the third-party service and concatenating the resulting clips) on the front-end, which would significantly reduce the amount of data transfers and probably result in faster user experience. Is doing so a good idea?

Comment: Would you trust a third party service with your Stack Exchange password? If not, why should I trust your service with my API key that you (or any malicious attacker who gets into your systems) could use to charge me money.

Comment: @PhilipKendall So can the third party itself or anyone who gets into their system...

Comment: @PhilipKendall Also, I might have used the wrong term. I might be able to request only their authentication token, but am not sure...

Comment: It's not clear why you need a back end at all.

Comment: @SimonB I would be happy to do without a backend (except for storing the api keys etc.), but it seems that one cannot submit third-party (in the real case, the third party is IBM Watson text-to-speech) requests from the front-end...

Answer (score 1):

> I could do everything (i.e. both sending request to the third-party service and concatenating the resulting clips) on the front-end, which would significantly reduce the amount of data transfers and probably result in faster user experience. Is doing so a good idea?

Obviously yes. It also means the user doesn't have to share their api key with you (assuming they trust your code) so a win win all round (unless you want to bill them a monthly fee for using your software rather than selling them a copy, looking at you office 365)

Comment: I might have used the wrong term. I might be able to request only their authentication token, but am not sure... However, I still do not understand your answer. 1. How does backend vs. front-end affect whether I need the user's api key? 2. The logic seems to be the opposite of what you wrote - if they trust my code, they would not mind sharing with me their api key (well, maybe only the auth token). 3. What does all this have to do with whether I want to charge a monthly or a one-time fee?